# Getting data from backend and displaying in Pug

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, pug

MongoDB --> Node.js --> Pug

I am trying get data from mongodb and show it in pug.
Here is my code:

```
router.get("/", isLoggedIn,  (req, res) => 
{
    res.status(200).send(pug.renderFile("./views/menti/takvim.pug", 
    {
        tasks: req.session.user.tasks,
    }))
})
```

The code above works fine but the I want to display every information in `req.session.user.tasks`(req.session.user.tasks is an array) in pug.
And here is my pug code:

```
html
    head
    body
      .main
        .tasks
```

I want add list with tasks which I get from MongoDB and Node.js. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your pug file look like?

Comment: It is just a basic html head body and a div file but I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over `tasks` array and display properties of each task with the following template:

```
ul
  each task, index in tasks
    li= index
      ul
        each val, key in task
          li= key + ': ' + val
```